# ASP.NET MVC3: EditView in Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

we are writing an ASP.NET MVC3 Application and want to do it "rich", for example by using bootstrap und modal dialogs.

I now wonder how to implement modal dialogs, without breaking all the cool staff from ASP.NET (ModelErrors, ...).

The workflow should be like this:

1. IndexView with a list of items, each item with an actionlink that shows a modal dialog

   ```
   @Ajax.ActionLink( 
            "Edit",  // Link Text
            "Edit",  // ActionMethod
            new { id = item.Id }, // RouteValues
            new AjaxOptions { 
                     HttpMethod = "Get", 
                     OnBegin = "modal.showModalDiv()", 
                     InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
                     UpdateTargetId = "modal-div", 
                     OnSuccess = "modal.ajaxSuccess()" }, 
            new { data-toggle = "edit-modal" } // HTML-Attributes
   )
   ```
2. The modal dialog (simple div styled with css) renders the editview (returned from controller actionmethode)

   ```
   [HttpGet]
   public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
       // Load Data and create Model
       var model = new ...
       return PartialView(model);
   }
   ```
3. The form in the edit view can be used to edit the item, including client-side validation

   ```
   @{
        AjaxOptions ajaxOptions = new AjaxOptions() {
             HttpMethod = "Post", OnSuccess="modal.hideModalDiv()"
        };
   }
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit"), ajaxOptions){


       ... element to edit item ...

       <input type="submit" value="submit" />
   }
   ```
4. When the submit edit controller-methode recognizes errors (not caught by client-side-validation) the page should be displayed again with model-errors. Otherwize the index-page should be shown or the table refreshed and the modal dialog closed.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, ItemModel model) {

         try{
             ...Save Item ...
             return RedirectToAction("Index")
         } catch (Exception ex){
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured")
             return PartialView(model);
         }

   }
   ```

My Problem is: How to implement step 4? Does Someone has an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, ItemModel model) 
{
  if(model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
  {
   return RedirectToAction("Index")
  }
  else
  {
   return PartialView(model);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. I think you did not get my problem. Your suggestion looks (except the ModelState.IsValid) exactly as mine. My problem is, how to handle the different types of responses (PartialViewResult to replace div vs. Redirectresult to Redirect or replace another div)?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've already solved this problem or found a work around but in case you have not I suspect if you were to return a partial view that contains javascript to do the redirection you could get the behaviour you describe.

For example:

RedirectToIndex.cshtml

```
@{ Layout = null; }
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = "@Url.Action("Index")";
</script>
```

Then update your action to return this partial view.

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Edit(Guid id, ItemModel model) {
try{
      //Save Item ...
      return PartialView("RedirectToIndex")
    } catch (Exception ex){
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "An error occured");
      return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Not the most graceful but should work, I say should as I have not tested this...